# Role of extreme experiences in psychological development

Tags: personality

<sub>**I would kindly like to ask for literature on the role of:**</sub>

- <sub>*Overcoming extreme experiences (suffering - psychological, physical, etc. -, fear, etc.), in personal development*</sub>
- <sub>*Sports psychology in personal development*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  The question is vague to me.  What do you mean when you ask about *"the role of overcoming extreme experiences in personal development"*?

Comment: and what do you mean when you ask about *"the role of sports psychology in personal development"*?

Comment: after a quick search on the second topic i was able to find the following:
https://hastebin.com/osokoniwed.erl not sure if all this literature is relevant, reason why i am asking. then on the hand of resilience psychology i found this https://hastebin.com/rebojuxeke.erl

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for in scholar.google.com you can just write key words that you put here and find thousands of good articles. if you have problem on determining which one to read. it is an other question.

Comment: about relevance of a litriture: you can read the abstructs of the litriture you found. in there, they talk about what is about and what they found. about extreeme cases and personal growth, you can use key words post trawmatic stress growth, resilience, post trawmatic stress disorder.